# What does “seas the day” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

What  does  the  idiom  **seas  the day**   mean?

An Indian  cricketor  tweets  that  he  seas  the  day. What  part  of  speech  is   *seas*  in  the  phrase?  Is  it   a verb? How  did  the  phrase  come  into  use?

I tried  to  find  the  meaning  of  *seas*  and  it  is  shown as the  plural  of  *sea*. I  could  not  find  its  meaning  as  a verb.  The  links  could  not  help me  arrive  at  the  meaning  of  seas  the  day. I  am  at  a loss to  know  whether  seas  is  a  verb  or  a  noun  and  what  the  phrase  actually  means.

Here  are  the  two  links  which  show  seas  both  as  a noun  and  a verb

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/seas

https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=30&T1=seas
Here is the link:
[Jasprit Bumrah Enjoys Leisure Time Amidst Sea Water, Picturesque Sky](https://sports.ndtv.com/cricket/jasprit-bumrahs-picturesque-tweet-has-enough-to-make-you-jealous-2130780)

Comment: It's a non-grammatical play on the well-known adage 'seize the day'. Humour trumping grammaticality. And certainly not an idiom (idioms are well-established usages).

Comment: I would respectfully ask you to consider frequenting ELL instead. The standard of the question before Laurel edited it was hardly what is expected on ELU. That's fine for a non-native speaker, but ELU is one of the very few sites aimed at fluent Anglophones and serious linguists rather than those less proficient. I would not consider myself competent enough to ask questions on a parallel site devoted to fluent French, Hindi, Czech ... speakers.

Comment: _An Indian cricketor tweets that seas the day._ (spelling mistake [cricketor] and grammatical error [cf _He said that take care_]). // _I here with enclose the link._ Misuse; _I herewith enclose the link._  is intended, but this shows lack of understanding of grammar. // Punctuation is often as important to get right as grammar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The expression in the article is a **[pun](https://www.thoughtco.com/pun-word-play-1691703)**, or a play on two words that sound or look similar.

In this case, **seas** sounds similar to the **seize** in **seize the day**, a translation of the Latin *carpe diem* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem)). [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seize%20the%20day):

> : to do the things one wants to do when there is the chance instead of waiting for a later time

The pun is that he is seizing the day at the sea, hence "seas the day." It's grammatically goofy, and that's part of the fun.

Comment: It depends on the exact quotation too. If it were *I seas the day*, then I'd say it was a pun on *I seize the day*. But if it were *he seas the day*, then *he **sees** the day* would be more likely. (Unless the quotation is from a cricket-playing Popeye, in which case I'd go with *see* … as a typo of the ungrammatical *I sees*.) It's not clear from the question if this comes from a real tweet (no source is provided) or if it's simply a fictional question.